# How to get the post's ID when I use the .map function (React/Firebase)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-props

I'm trying to get the post's ID when I'm mapping them in a search component. The posts are the results of the search essentially.

A post looks like this in my firebase database.
[image: post]

I can of course map everything from this post inside the search results section, like so:

```
<List
    inverted
    animated
    divided
    relaxed="very"
    style={{ width: '322.02px' }}
>
    {Object.keys(results).map(key => (
        <List.Item
            key={key}
            as={Link}
            to={`/post/${results[key].id}`}
        >
            <List.Content floated="right">
                <TimeAgo
                    datetime={new Date(results[key].createdAt)}
                    locale="en"
                    style={{ fontSize: '0.7em', marginTop: '-3px' }}
                />
            </List.Content>
            <Image
                avatar
                verticalAlign="middle"
                src={results[key].createdByPhotoURL}
                style={{ marginTop: '3px' }}
            />
            <List.Content>
                <List.Header>{results[key].createdBy}</List.Header>
                <List.Description
                    style={{
                        overflow: 'hidden',
                        whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
                        textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
                        marginTop: '4px',
                        maxWidth: '200px'
                    }}
                >
                    {results[key].message}
                </List.Description>
            </List.Content>
        </List.Item>
    ))}
</List>
```

But how can I get the ID? My plan is to take the current post ID and pass it to another component which then will display the whole post, so I can edit in the future, etc etc...

Is it possible to get the ID or is there a better solution for this?

I appreciate the answers in advance!

Comment: Is the `key` not the Order ID in this example?

Comment: I tried to use it that way but it says its undefined. I tried `results[key]` and also `results[key].key`

Comment: On a side note, you should put your `List.Item` into its own component, otherwise you have to re-render the whole list if one of the item changes.

Comment: Noted! I'll do that for sure, thanks

Comment: @David. You mentioned you tried `results[key]` and `results[key].key`. Did you try just `key`?
`results[key]` is the object.
`results[key].key` should be undefined.
`key` is the actual key / ID of the element.